# lambda returns '1' all time

Tags: c++, gcc, lambda, g++, return

Have code like this

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() 
{ 
  cout<<[](){ return 0;};
  cout<<[](){ return 3.2;};
  cout<<[](){ return true;};
  cout<<[](){ return false;};
  cout<<[](){ return "Hello world!";};
  cout<<[]()->int{ return 0;};
  cout<<[]()->double{ return 3.2;};
  cout<<[]()->bool{ return true;};
  cout<<[]()->bool{ return false;};
  cout<<[]()->const char*{ return "Hello world!";};
  return 0;
}
```

Compile it with `gcc version 4.8.2` and my output is only `1111111111`.
Why only "1"?

Comment: You never call the lambdas:  `[](){ return 10;}` vs `([](){ return 10;})()`.

Comment: In VS 2013 I get the error message "binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'main::<lambda [..]", i.e. you put the lambda into the stream. gcc seems to convert it to an integer?

Comment: Lambdas with no captures are implicitly convertible to a function pointer, which in turn is implicitly convertible to `bool`.

Comment: Please don't downvote. When the compiler doesn't complain, this issue *is* hard to spot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When a lambda expression has no capture, it is implicitly convertible to a function pointer.

A function pointer, in turn, is implicitly convertible to `bool`, yielding `true` if the pointer is not null, which gets printed.

If you `cout << std::boolalpha` before your outputs, [you'll see `truetruetrue....` printed instead](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/de3234b85686a77d).

If you capture something in your lambda, then it is no longer convertible to a function pointer, and [you'd get a compiler error](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/135a3369b2cee9c7).

If you want to print the result returned by calling the lambda, then you need `()`, as others have pointed out.

Answer (score 5):

What you say:

```
cout<<[](){ return 0;};
```

What you want to say:

```
cout<<[](){ return 0;}();
```

See the bracket?

Answer (score 5):

What if you did this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void foo()
{
}
int main() 
{ 
  cout<<foo;
  return 0;
}
```

You're not calling the method, but attempting to print its address. The overload `operator <<(bool)` for `cout` is chosen, thus for any valid function you attempt to print, you get a `1`.

To actually, call the function (or lambadas), add `()`.

Comment: Thanks for explaining why I get  "1" each time.