# Why c++ Lambda Expression Not working

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I am very much new to this feature, I was just reading about  Lambda expression in c++ and tried to implement it in a simple program.

```
int main()
{
  std::string name;
  int a = 5;
  std::cout << "What is your name? ";
  getline (std::cin, name);
  for([&](){a = 7;};a > 0; a--)
  {
    std::cout << "Hello, " << name << "!\n";
  }
}
```

but its not working as I thought it will.. 
My assumption : `[&](){a = 7;}`  this will change value of variable a to 7 from 5 but its not..
Is there anything wrong in code?? Or just my assumption is incorrect?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [lambda returns '1' all time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28273891/lambda-returns-1-all-time)

Comment: You created the lambda and threw it away. You need to invoke the () operator to run it.

Comment: @RaymondChen got it.. that solved the issue.. Thanks.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption is correct provided you **invoke** it.

> [&]: implicitly capture by reference. All local names can be used. All local variables are
>   accessed by reference.

You are able to access the local variable but the lambda itself is not getting called. This is what happening in your code:

`Lambda Expression without capture -> functionPtr -> bool (true for non-null functionPtr)`

where `->` is implicit conversion

Instead do `(lambdaExpression)()` or `lambdaExpression()` to invoke it.